# Python writing and reading csv docs like a shallow grid?

Tags: python

I find it strange that there is no built in function to just take the entire contents of an excel-produced csv file and just place them on a nested list so that it makes a 2D matrix.

Is there any reason why this is impractical/not standard?

I am putting my own CSV code together to do it, but I am already bumping into annoying hurdles wanting to do simple stuff like write columns instead of rows and whatnot.

Is there any reason I should consider a completely different approach?

the rationale is that using grids in, say, PyQt is so simple and it seems like the same kind of designing could translate seamlessly to reading and writing simple spreadsheets ie:

```
name , myname
age , myage
xvals, yvals
1,1
2,4
3,9
```

turns into

```
[[name,myname],[age,myage],[xvals,yvals],[1,1],[2,4],[3,9]]
```

Comment: you could transpose 2d arrays (to exchange columns and rows) using: `a.T` if `a` is a numpy array or `zip(*a)` if `a` is a nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Numpy and its loadtxt function. It does exactly what you want :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

and for writing, you can use the savetxt function :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Also there is functions to read directly from Excel files :

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/

http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/

Comment: that loads the text just fine. how about writing?

Comment: Edited answer to add writing function

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in function for csv files for python. The bellow lines of code does exactly what you want.

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Or even better thanks to J.F. Sebastian

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    a2d=list(csv.reader(f))
```

Sample csv file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

[Source](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: this is what I'm using to build my own function, but I want something more comprehensive. I'm talking about basically directly linking each cell to a spot in my nested list. Ideally doing some data recognition/validation for numbers vs. strings.

Comment: @RodericDay Look above your comment.